# AWS S3 and Lambda .NET - Copying file between folders changes accessibility

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-core, aws-lambda

I'm going through a very weird problem with AWS S3 and Lambda function in .NET Core.
I'm copying (or better cloning) via .NET a "folder" within the same bucket.
Those folders are accessible as CDN via specific domain.

I managed to perform recursive copy of "folder" A to folder "B".

For some weird reason some of the copied files are not accessible via URL. 
For example: */A/images/picture.png* and */B/images/picture.png*

I checked the metadata and the ACL for file on A and B and it looks the same.
But yet I get an AccessDenied when I try to browse to the B file.

This is an extract of my code, maybe someone could help me out.
I've disabled *Encryption*, and I gave *OwnerFullAccess* to the copied.

```
CopyObjectResponse response = await awsCDNS3Client.CopyObjectAsync(new CopyObjectRequest
{
    MetadataDirective = S3MetadataDirective.COPY,
    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.BucketOwnerFullControl,
    ServerSideEncryptionMethod = ServerSideEncryptionMethod.None,
    SourceBucket = sourceBucket,
    SourceKey = sourceKey,
    DestinationBucket = destinationBucket,
    DestinationKey = destinationKey
});
```

```
var uploadRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
{
    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.BucketOwnerFullControl,
    BucketName = bucketName,
    Key = bucketObjectKey,
    StorageClass = S3StorageClass.Standard,
    AutoCloseStream = true,
    PartSize = Bucket.MiminumPartSize,
    ServerSideEncryptionMethod = ServerSideEncryptionMethod.None
};
```

And as result of the copied I get AccessDenied (the object actually exist).

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>AAAAAA</RequestId>
<HostId>
NNNNNN</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: How are you trying to "browse" the B file? Are you sure A file doesn't have public read ACL?

Comment: C# code is not helpful here. You should check your S3 bucket policy and IAM policy first.

Comment: Thanks all, I found answer to my question, if you're curious check below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer to my own question.

The object X on folder A and folder B was showing a different Owner when called get-object-acl via CLI.

What I've done is set REPLACE metadata S3MetadataDirective on the CopyRequest.
In this way I've got the proper (?!) previous Owner.

But the trouble was not finished there.
At this point I got to access the file via browser. Unfortunately the browser was dowloading it instead of showing in on page (CSS and JS).

What, again, I had to to is to set the Header.ContentType to the proper MIME.
Such a property is non available at inline declaration, so you have to create instance and set it later.

My fault for many things, but as well Documentation and SDK have huge, huge margin of improvement.

Thanks